# Generic class to implement function according to type of generic

Tags: swift

I have a generic class which needs to return some data according to the type of generic.
The following solution works for concrete implementations and not for protocols such as CaseIteratable. Is there a workaround for this? even if inside `SomeThing` I could check for case iteratable it would be fine, but compiler does not allow that

```
struct SomeThing<T>: DoSomething {
    let value: T

    func doSomething() {
        if let doable = value as? DoSomething {
            doable.doSomething()
        }
    }
}

protocol DoSomething {
    func doSomething()
}

extension Bool: DoSomething {
    func doSomething() {
        "bool action"
    }
}

// Won't compile
extension CaseIterable: DoSomething where Self: RawRepresentable {
    func doSomething() {
        "bool action"
    }
}
```

I also tried to add extensions for something but ends up with the same problem

```
extension SomeThing: DoSomething where T: Bool {}
extension SomeThing: DoSomething where T: CaseIteratable {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Swift documentation

> When you define a protocol extension, you can specify constraints that
>   conforming types must satisfy before the methods and properties of the
>   extension are available. You write these constraints after the name of
>   the protocol you’re extending by writing a generic where clause. For
>   more about generic where clauses, see [Generic Where Clauses](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID192).
>
> [protocol extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID521)

```
struct SomeThing<T>: DoSomething {
    let value: T

    func doSomething() {
        if let doable = value as? DoSomething {
            doable.doSomething()
        }
    }
}

protocol DoSomething {
    func doSomething()
}

extension Bool: DoSomething {
    func doSomething() {
        "bool action"
    }
}

// this will compiles
extension CaseIterable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == Bool {
    func doSomething() {
        "bool action"
    }
}

extension CaseIterable where Self: DoSomething {}
```

And this is another answer from Github issue

> It is because a constraint is needed for conformance purposes, otherwise, the compiler thinks it is an inheritance.
>
> Source: [Extension of protocol cannot have inheritance clause](https://gist.github.com/SpacyRicochet/88a1553ea931e867923d#gistcomment-2152380)

Hope this will helps

Comment: I don't think this will work, caseiteratable does not conform to DoSomething which means `if let doable = value as? DoSomething` fails, and that's the main problem. I mean the code compiles but it doesn't function as expected

Comment: I checked with this code
`let do = SomeThing(value: true)`

 `do.doSomething()`

and this was working and the output is `bool action` as in the `extension Bool: DoSomething` override implementation

Comment: it only works for bool doesn't work for CaseIterable. You are printing "bool action" on both functions that's probably why you didn't notice